# How to get a friend's post of facebook sdk v4

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook SDK v4 to get all the posts of a friend. I use the following code

```
FBSDKLoginManager* loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"user_posts"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError* error) {
        if (error) {
            // Process error
            NSLog(@"");
        } else if (result.isCancelled) {
            // Handle cancellations
            NSLog(@"");
        } else {
            // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
            // should check if specific permissions missing
            if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"user_posts"]) {
                FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                              initWithGraphPath:@"/10002434324342/posts"
                                              parameters:nil
                                              HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
                [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                                      id result,
                                                      NSError *error) {
                    // Handle the result
                    if (error) {
                        NSLog(@"");
                    }
                }];
            }

        }
    }];
```

10002434324342 is an example of facebookID. It just return an empty data list.

Can anyone tell me how to do this

Answer (score 1):

Friend permissions have been removed with v2.0, you can only get data of users who authorized your App too, with the correct permissions. `user_posts` should always be used with `/me/posts`.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: if a facebook friend of the logged in user authorize my app too, then can I use user_posts permission to get post of the friend?

Comment: you can use /me/posts to get his posts when he uses your app

Comment: ah no, you misunderstood me, I will explain the situation, user A login facebook on my app, and user A want to get posts of B (a A's friend).

Comment: you can try it, but i don´t think it would work. you are not supposed to read stuff from friends. they can authorize your app and you can read them with THEIR access token.

Comment: You cannot use user A's access token to access another user's posts, regardless if they're friends or not. If user B also uses your app, you can use user B's access token to access their posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                               initWithGraphPath:@"/{user-id-a}/friends/{user-id-b}"
                                      parameters:params
                                      HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error) {
    // Handle the result
}];
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/friends